# Right align single element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, bootstrap-5

I want to right align a single element in a dropdown list with Bootstrap 5. Usually I use "justify-content-end" for it, but this does not do so.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is just the example from the bootstrap homepage. I tried "justify-content-end" at <li> and at <a> tag. For example, I only want "Another action" to be right aligned, the other two left aligned.

Comment: Bootstrap 5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element with a class of `dropdown-item` is set to `display: block` (meaning it takes up the whole width of the parent element). If you want the text of "Another Action" to be right aligned, means you need to set a class of `text-end` on the `<a>` element

Comment: That was it - thank you very much!